# How to Serialize a Json Object?

Tags: java, json, serialization, firebase-realtime-database, gson

I want to insert a json object into my firebase database which is of the following format:-

```
{
   "0":{
      "code":"BK 0000184",
      "isbn":"9788184821475",
      "title":"Stories Of Wisdom (586)",
      "qty":"1",
      "price":"70",
      "gross_value":"70.0",
      "discountAmount":"0",
      "discount":"0.0",
      "netValue":"70.0"
   },
   "orderInfo":{
      "modeOfPayment":"cash",
      "typeof_payment":"60 days",
      "expected_date":"5",
      "distributor_company":"Anurag Agency ",
      "contact_person_name":"Anurag",
      "company_addresss":"Model colony ",
      "contactNumber":"9846795359",
      "date":"26\/10\/2017",
      "distributorId":"-KxCpz1gaLUkKP4EvweX",
      "shipping_address1":"Model colony",
      "shipping_state":"Maharashtra",
      "shipping_city":"Pune",
      "shipping_person_number":"9846795359",
      "shipping_person_name":"Anurag",
      "shipping_company":"Anurag Agency",
      "delivery_address1":"Model colony",
      "delivery_state":"Maharashtra",
      "delivery_city":"Pune",
      "delivery_person_number":"9846795359",
      "delivery_person_name":"Anurag",
      "delivery_company":"Anurag Agency"
   },
   "1":{
      "code":"BK 0000356",
      "isbn":"9788189999230",
      "title":"Krishna (501)",
      "qty":"1",
      "price":"70",
      "gross_value":"70.0",
      "discountAmount":"0",
      "discount":"0.0",
      "netValue":"70.0"
   }
}
```

There will be more entries added to this json object with keys 0 to 20 and one for orderInfo. I was using a mysql database before this with php where I would simply parse and insert the values into respected columns.
I am getting a exception as follows:-
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class org.json.JSONObject

What are my best options to achieve this objective?
Any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: did u try `JSON.stringify(object)` ?

Comment: I have never used stringify in java.However I tried toString which is similar and it inserted the json as a long string. Anyways Thank you so much @Tarek

Comment: apologies, i didnt notice its java. My assumption was this is javascript.